# Parsing file name in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have a file name `SandersCoffeNetwork201604211107`. I would like create a two new column in SSIS using derived column. However I need an expression that would separate the date from the file name

First column `FileFromDate`
                       2016-04-21

2nd column `FileToDate`
                       2016-11-07

Please suggest.....

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the file name is stored in a variable `@[User::Filename]`

*FileToDate*

```
SUBSTRING(RIGHT(@[User::Filename],12), 1, 4 ) + "-" +
SUBSTRING(RIGHT(@[User::Filename],4), 1, 2 ) + "-" +
SUBSTRING(RIGHT(@[User::Filename],2), 1, 2 )
```

*FileFromDate*

```
SUBSTRING(RIGHT(@[User::Filename],12), 1, 4 ) + "-" +
SUBSTRING(RIGHT(@[User::Filename],8), 1, 2 ) + "-" +
SUBSTRING(RIGHT(@[User::Filename],6), 1, 2 )
```

**If the value is not stored in a variable**

*FileToDate*

```
SUBSTRING(RIGHT("SandersCoffeNetwork201604211107",12), 1, 4 ) + "-" +
SUBSTRING(RIGHT("SandersCoffeNetwork201604211107",4), 1, 2 ) + "-" +
SUBSTRING(RIGHT("SandersCoffeNetwork201604211107",2), 1, 2 )
```

*FileFromDate*

```
SUBSTRING(RIGHT("SandersCoffeNetwork201604211107",12), 1, 4 ) + "-" +
SUBSTRING(RIGHT("SandersCoffeNetwork201604211107",8), 1, 2 ) + "-" +
SUBSTRING(RIGHT("SandersCoffeNetwork201604211107",6), 1, 2 )
```

Comment: Thanks for replying guys.

Comment: @cynthia0421 if this answer solved ur issue you have to [accept it](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) or upvote it if you found it helpful else give a reply

Comment: @cynthia0421 saying thanks is not the way to work on stackoverflow